# Not able to view Hystrix Report on Hystrix Dashboard

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, hystrix

I have a rest application(cxf based) which internally calls soap  web services. I want to integrate *hystrix* in to my rest application.

1) Modified the below hystrix demo source code with our existing services data and deployed the rest application.

https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/tree/master/hystrix-examples/src/main/java/com/netflix/hystrix/examples/demo

2) I downloaded ***hystrix-dashboard*** war file and deployed in to tomcat and I can see the hystrix dashboard home page.

Now when I am trying to monitor the stream by providing the hystrix integrated rest application url.Empty page with hystrix icon is getting displayed. When I look IE developer console, it shows below error

**EventSource is not defined.**

```
  //code snippet from ie developer console
  var proxyStream = "../proxy.stream?origin=http://localhost:8080/hystrix/hystrix.stream;
  // start the EventSource which will open a streaming connection to the server
  var source = new EventSource(proxyStream);
```

Note: both are deployed on same machine - localhost

Comment: Can you try the same with another browser such as Firefox or chrome ?

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to add the following code :

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistration() {
  ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new     HystrixMetricsStreamServlet(), "/hystrix.stream"); 
  return registration;
}
```

You also to ensure that the `/hystrix.stream` isn't secured.